# Issue when trying to route a path that ends with a '.'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm trying to route a path like this:

```
http://www.wikipediamaze.com/wiki/Washington,_D.C.
```

The routing framework is not picking this up as a valid route and giving me a "Cannot find resource" error. Anyone know how I can get around this? It's not even getting to my controller factory so it's as if it doesn't even recognize it as a route or perhaps looking for an actual file.

I don't have any problems with similar routes like this:

```
http://www.wikipediamaze.com/wiki/United_States
http://www.wikipediamaze.com/wiki/Canadian_Bacon_(film)
```

but anytime I end a url with a '.' it doesn't route it. If I do this it works:

```
http://www.wikipediamaze.com/wiki/?topic=Washington,_D.C.
```

The route that I have setup looks like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "wiki",
    "wiki/{topic}",
    new { controller = "game", action = "continue", topic = "" }
);
```

Comment: What is the route that you want to pick it up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dot is being interpreted as the beginning of a file extension as in

```
mypage.mvc or index.aspx
```

I wouldn't know the first clue about how to fix it, although the form

```
http://www.wikipediamaze.com/wiki/?topic=Washington,_D.C.
```

looks very clear and concise to me.  This form works because MVC automatically knows that a question mark is going to be followed by a named parameter, and not another partial route.

Comment: The issue is that I'm screen scraping the wikipedia site and using the links as is on the page:

    <a href="/wiki/Washington,_D.C.">Washington D.C</a>

I don't want to have to rewrite all the links to the form 
    
    /wiki/?topic=Washington,_D.C.

Comment: Can you strip off the last period if it exists?

Comment: The problem is that when my contreller action gets called the topic is passed in which I then use to screen-scrape wikipedia. so it matches www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Washington,_D.C.